# Vue 3 class attribute appears to ignore ref

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm super lost. The watch is getting hit when the currentPresetName changes and isDarkMode is getting updated. For whatever reason, it seems as though `:class` is completely ignoring my ref. It checks it on the initial load and then never reacts.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useColors } from "vuestic-ui";

const { currentPresetName } = useColors();

const isDarkMode = ref();

watch(currentPresetName, () => {
  isDarkMode.value = currentPresetName.value === 'dark';
})
</script>
<template>
  <div :class="['homeBackground', isDarkMode ? 'backgroundDark' : '']" v-once></div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" >
.homeBackground {
  height: 93vh;
  background-image: url('@/assets/LargeLogo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 40vw;
  background-color: unset !important;
}

.backgroundDark {
  background-image: url('@/assets/LargeLogo-Dark.png');

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove [`v-once`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once) and it will work as expected. The *"bug"* is a feature. It's what `v-once` does:

> *On subsequent re-renders, the element/component and all its children will be treated as static content and skipped. This can be used to optimize update performance.*

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need an intermediate ref `isDarkMode`. Like don't clutter code with variables that used only once on the next line and initialized with a couple of words.

Second use `watch` only if you mutate data, for derived calculated values like `isDarkMode` use `computed`.

Third move your static `homeBackground` class to `class` static attribute so it would be obvious which classes are static and which ones are dynamic.

And the last but the most important:
*try to remove `v-once` since `currentPresetName` could change to the needed `dark` value after the first rendering of the element.*

JS expressions inside a template are `computed` so try:

```
<div class="homeBackground" :class="{backgroundDark: currentPresetName === 'dark'}"></div>
```

Comment: I just tried the first suggestion and it does not work property. It generates
``<div class="homeBackground backgroundDark toFullStatuses deconFullStatuses"></div>``

I was using a intermediate because I had tried something similar and had gotten similar results.

I was using watch, because computed was not picking up the change. I can put a console.log() in the watch function and it will show the value is set accordingly. 
I was using a ref to try and ensure vue reactivity.

Comment: @BondAddict looks working fine, what is the problem? backgroundDark is here

Comment: @BondAddict extra classes go from the parent component

Comment: Nanashev its there whether or not the condition is true. Also, toFullStatuses and deconFullStatuses are string prototypes (extension methods)  not classes. It should show ``<div class="homeBackground backgroundDark"></div>`` when currentPresetName is dark and otherwise `` <div class="homeBackground"></div>``

Comment: @BondAddict these classes injected from the parent component, I need your parent component...